# URL https :".." when used then unable to get content of page

Tags: windows, visual-c++, https, mfc, dhtmlx-scheduler

i used mfc active x control and navigate the url.
as url is https:"..." so i am unable to get the content of page.

following is the code i used.

```
m_cstrURL = L"https:\\......" like that

m_webBrowser.Navigate(m_cstrURL.operator LPCWSTR(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);    

IHTMLDocument2 *document = (IHTMLDocument2 *)m_webBrowser.get_Document() ; 

    HRESULT hresult = document->get_body(&iSource);

    if(iSource)
    {
        iSource->get_innerText(&btsrSource); 
        strSource=btsrSource.m_str; 
    }
```

so if url contains the https: my `get_body` failed.
i mean isource is null..

Comment: Sorry, but this is a bit hard to understand. Why do you use `https:\ `? It should be `https://`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Gabor, by mistake that was written.
Anyways thank you,for attending my question.
i just found the solution for that.
i was using wrong event handler as, NavigateComplete2 instead i used DocumentComplete.
it is working....